# Ubuntu GNOME desktop glitch on multuple monitors

Tags: 20.04, gnome, multiple-monitors, 22.04

I do not even know how to describe this issue, I tried to search for it, but any of the wordings I tried seems to fail...

I am using Ubuntu 22.04; before this, I was using 20.04; the problem carried on to both. I did not find any answer before, so I let it go, but it became annoying, and I wanted to solve it. I am using GNOME as my desktop env.

When I drag on my main desktop (about 10 inches bigger than my second screen), I get a secondary drag starting on my secondary screen?? I don't know how to describe it, so I will show it.

https://youtu.be/MWCwu4LE4KE

How do I fix this...

Here is the output for `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`:

```bash
kothar@kothar-ubuntu:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA104 [GeForce RTX 3070] (rev a1)
    DeviceName: VGA
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GA104 [GeForce RTX 3070]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Here is my driver as well:

```bash
kothar@kothar-ubuntu:~$ nvidia-smi
Tue Feb  7 10:55:03 2023       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.78.01    Driver Version: 525.78.01    CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   39C    P5    24W / 220W |   1986MiB /  8192MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1373      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg               1193MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1502      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              337MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2473      G   ...292627441304305762,131072      351MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

(I could not try anything as I do not have much expertise on Linux distros. This is a fresh install of Linux, so I don't think it is something I have installed.)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: I have no idea how to fix it, but that's a cool and helpful video.

Comment: @Pilot6 edited rn

Comment: Which Nvidia driver is installed?

Comment: Added that too @Pilot6

Comment: Try another driver, e.g. 515

Comment: And also check if you are using Xorg or wyland.

Comment: If i use any other driver, i get window dragging issue https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/ud2l2l/2204_freezinglagging_when_dragging_windows/ @Pilot6

Comment: I am using Xorg